# Where exactly does A Certain Scientific Accelerator fit in the timeline?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index, a-certain-scientific-railgun, a-certain-scientific-accelerator

Where exactly does A Certain Scientific Accelerator take place in the timeline? I know it'd some time after Accelerator's gunshot wound by the necklace but that's about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wondering about the episode order:

The broadcasted *Accelerator* S1 arc happens after *Index* S1, episode 17 and *Railgun S*, episode 24.

Which means the *Accelerator* S1 happens before *Index* S1, episode 18 and *Index* S2, episode 1, and *Index* S1 episodes 19-24, and *Index* S2, episodes 2-5.

*Index* S2, episodes 2-5, happens before *A Certain Magical and Scientific Ensemble*, which happens before the *Index* S2, episodes 6-7, which happens before the Index *Miracle of Endymion* movie, which happens before *Index* S2 episodes 8-24, and *Index* S3.

Comment: So Accelerator happens between index 1 episodes 17 and 18? Like all of it? This timeline gets confusing

Comment: A lot of things happen in parallel. Time is also skipped, so it doesn't go day by day (between arcs).

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this. Can you explain how you narrowed it down? I don't remember anything that gave away the timeline

Comment: You have to look through the anime chronology. The dates are mentioned in some episodes (and/or can be cross-referenced with the novel) and progress accordingly with the story arc. https://toarumajutsunoindex.fandom.com/wiki/Anime_Timeline